# Gitlab with Bash on Windows

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to have Gitlab execute projects with Bash shell on Windows? I have configured my runner with the following configuration, but it doesn't work (keep on pending status):

```
[[runners]]
  name = "IchsanWin8Bash"
  url = "https://gitlab.local/ci"
  token = "7fa094668bd46c27e7fcf0041d328e"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "bash"
  [runners.ssh]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = ""
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
  [runners.parallels]
    base_name = ""
    disable_snapshots = false
  [runners.virtualbox]
    base_name = ""
    disable_snapshots = false
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
```

The `bash` command is accessible as I put this on the env PATH: C:\Users\ichsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin

Answer (score 0):

No, [that is not supported](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/executors/shell.md). The available shells on Windows are CMD (default) and Powershell (highly recommended).

However, you may still be able to execute Bash commands where you really need to. Since the introduction of the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide), you can drop down into Bash from any Windows shell on a properly configured machine. You will not be able to use Bash commands in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but you ought to be able to use them in scripts called *from* `.gitlab-ci.yml` (which you're doing anyway, right?).